# How to solve a Poisson's differential equation with a boundary condition at infinity?

Tags: differential-equations, expression-manipulation, physics

Context: This question is relevant to the physical problem of calculating potential for a set of p-n-p junctions. 
We have to solve a Poisson's differential equation for a p-n-p junction with potential equal zero outside it on the left and right sides. For simplification and due to symmetry law we analyze only right side from 0 to some delta (from which potential is the same as for Infinity) and do not analyze left side.  Boundary conditions are that in point on Infinity function and its 1st derivative is equal 0. Derivative in x=0 is equal 0.
Alpha is a random very small number for Fermi step.
In code bcd are boundary conditions

```
α = 0.00001;
bcd1 = ϕ'[0] == 0;
bcd2 = ϕ'[Infinity] == 0;
bcd3 = ϕ[Infinity] == 0;
eqn = Div[ Grad  [ϕ[x], x], x] == -((1/(Exp [(x - 1)/α] + 1)) - (1/Exp [((-x - 1)/α)] + 1) + Exp[-ϕ[x]] - Exp [ϕ[x]]);
DSolve[{eqn, bcd1, bcd2, bcd3}, ϕ, {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

i have tried to use numbers(some delta from which Phi is 0) instead of Infinity or set boundary conditions like

```
ϕ'[x == 0] == 0
ϕ[x == -Infinity] == 0
ϕ'[x == -Infinity] == 0
```

and put it directly into eqn but it does not seem to work. And I obtain as a result

```
DSolve[{Div[Grad[\[Phi][x],x],x] ==  1 + E^(-100000. (-1 - x)) - E^-\[Phi][x] + E^\[Phi][x] - 1/( 1 + E^(100000. (-1 + x))), Derivative[1][\[Phi]][0] == 0, Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Infinity]] == 0, \[Phi][\[Infinity]] ==  0}, \[Phi], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

If I try to vary boundary conditions or use more complex version of equation I obtain this

```
DSolve::dsvar: ∞ (-∞..) cannot be used as a variable.
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is `exp` supposed to denote the exponentional function? Then it should be `Exp[ ... ]`, not `exp(...)`.

Comment: Moreover, you have three boundary conditions for a an elliptic second order differential equation which should allow for only two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
 1) I have tried both Exp[ ] and exp ( ) to check correct form, it was a mistype. I corrected it. 
2) Can you please explain why it supports only 2 boundary conditions? For example if we take x from -Infinity to Infinity, as it is in original case, we would have 5 boundary conditions. As far as I know, similar problems are solvable with 5 conditions 
p.s.(I have tried to solve it with only 2 boundary conditions and still got no result thou)

Comment: We are solving Boundary value problem, not Cauchy problem so why we can not set more boundary conditions?

Comment: Because Poisson problems are well-posed only for at most one boundary condition per boundary component (typically, either Dirichlet, Neumann, or Robin boundary conditions). Also recall how you solve ODEs analytically (this one is actually an ODE): For second order equations, you obtain precisely two integration constants. So you can apply two initial conditions (for a Cauchy problem) or one boundary condition per boundary component of the interval (for boundary value problems).

Comment: From boundary conditions Phi(Infinitty)=0 We can see that 1st constant is equal 0 and ϕ'[Infinity] =0 gives us C2= -delta. So constants are well defined except for 0<x<delta. So, what exactly can you recommend to solve it? I am quite sure that I can solve it with 3 boundary conditions on paper, so it is strange that it can not be solved like that.

Comment: For example we have p-n junction in a set of p-n junctions. We can tell that potential on - and + Infinity is equal 0 as well as its derivatives, in approximately contact point potential has a change so we have ϕ'[0] == 0. As you can see we have 5 boundary conditions from physics. Such system is described by Poisson equation. It is a well known problem as far as I know. So why we must have one boundary condition per boundary component?
Also this problem can be solved using probability schemes but I am quite sure that it would be beyond wolfram's capabilities.

Comment: _Sigh._ Then try it on paper. It won't work in general, only in exceptional cases. You cannot beat the laws of math. It is like solving 3 linear equations in two variables. That can only work if the equations are redundant which is generically not the case. I strongly suggest to revise your physical model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am quite sure that this physical model is correct and I am just using wrong methods. Because we have solved it on paper and obtained approximate numbers.

Comment: As for contact points: You probably only know that the limits of the $\phi$ or its  derivative from the left and right side have to coincide. That does not imply that it is `0`. But I am not very knowledgeable about semi conductors.

Comment: From physics on the left and right sides potential is equal 0 due to compensation. In middle point we have applied Fermi step approximation ((1/(Exp [(x - 1)/α] + 1)) to solve discontinuity Phi(-delta, +0)= Phi(-delta, -0); Phi'(-delta, +0)= Phi'(-delta, -0)